# oriented bounding box obtained applying principal component analysis

Tags: pca

Is there a theorem indicating that the OBB obtained by PCA from a point cloud is almost the same (or the same) than the one obtained with a subset of points (regularly distributed) on the surface of this point cloud ?

So that if you are given a set of points laying on the boundary of an object you do not need to use internal points to obtain the best OBB using PCA

Comment: The answers will depend on how you use PCA to compute an OBB (and, to some extent, what you mean by the "surface" of a point cloud.)